# What could cause all sub-pages to redirect to the main page?

Tags: 2010, alternate-access-mapping, redirect

After quite a long break, I've come back to do some work on our Sharepoint-based Portal. I went to our test server and found that, when I click on a link to a sub-page, the main page gets reloaded. This happens for all the sub-pages on the main page.

I checked the logs and see that the sub-page does get loaded. The last message in the log seems to suggest that the sub-page was found. There are no error messages.

Firebug shows that the sub-page is requested but a 302 return code is sent and the main page is reloaded.

I have looked in the ULS logs and I can se no indication of an error. Here is a part of the logs where the requested page (Support-Sitzung.aspx) is handled and then the home page (Portal.aspx) appears in the log.

```
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Usage Infrastructure    d0i2    Verbose Successfully added requestUsageEntry to CollectUsageData with url http://portalt/company/intranet/en/Pages/Support-Sitzung.aspx 0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Verbose Leaving Monitored Scope (LogRequestUsage). Execution Time=0.0536381020492828    0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose ____SQL Query Count=0   0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose ____Execution Time=0.0536381020492828   0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Verbose Entering monitored scope (ForceDehydrateHttpContextWorkflows)   0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Verbose Leaving Monitored Scope (ForceDehydrateHttpContextWorkflows). Execution Time=0.00446984183744023    0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose ____Execution Time=0.00446984183744023  0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Verbose Entering monitored scope (EndRequestHandler SPRequest Disposal) 0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   General narq    Verbose Releasing SPRequest with allocation Id {244607AB-30E6-40A5-8B74-56803403FD9D}   0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Verbose Leaving Monitored Scope (EndRequestHandler SPRequest Disposal). Execution Time=0.273498447428374    0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose ____SQL Query Count=0   0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose ____Execution Time=0.273498447428374    0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Usage Infrastructure    d0hz    Verbose Starting write trace for type Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPRequestUsageEntry with correlationID 0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95   0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Usage Infrastructure    d0i0    Verbose Successful wrote trace for type Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPRequestUsageEntry with correlationID 0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95 0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://portalt:80/company/intranet/en/Pages/Support-Sitzung.aspx)). Execution Time=65.2677924149578   0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose ____SPRequest Objects=3 0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose ____SQL Query Count=6   0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose ____Execution Time=65.2677924149578 0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose ____Current User=XXX\myuser 0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose ____WebPart Events Offsets=1    0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose ____Service Calls=0 0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose ____Page Checkout Level=Draft   0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose ____Current SharePoint Operations=0 0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose ____Critical Events=0   0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose ____Log Correlation Id=0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95 0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.33  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    77a3    Verbose Ending correlation. 0d4913d2-af73-4d2a-8540-7ee5f592ac95
01.07.2013 10:02:43.34  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    9gc5    Verbose Thread change; resetting trace level override to 0; resetting correlation to empty list 
01.07.2013 10:02:43.34  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   General 6t8b    Verbose Looking up context  site http://portalt:80/company/intranet/en/Pages/Portal.aspx in the farm SharePoint_Config  
01.07.2013 10:02:43.34  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   General 6t8d    Verbose Looking up the additional information about the typical site http://portalt:80/company/intranet/en/Pages/Portal.aspx.   
01.07.2013 10:02:43.34  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   General 6t8f    Verbose Site lookup is replacing http://portalt:80/company/intranet/en/Pages/Portal.aspx with the alternate access url http://portalt.  
01.07.2013 10:02:43.34  w3wp.exe (0x1700)   0x0DEC  SharePoint Foundation   General 6t8g    Verbose Looking up typical site http://portalt:80/company/intranet/en/Pages/Portal.aspx in web application SPWebApplication Name=SharePoint - 80.
```

I also notice that, if I open a browser on the server directly and go to one of these sub-pages, then there is no redirection - it works.

Has anyone else had this? Any suggestion where I might look for more information?

**UPDATE**

<strike>I just had a closer look at the Sharepoint logs and saw that the page request is recognised but then this message comes:</strike>

`Site lookup is replacing http://servername:80/acme/intranet/de/Seiten/Favoriten.aspx with the alternate access url http://servername`

It really is a long time since I set up this portal. What is meant by 'alternate access' and what might cause it to trigger at this point?

Seems this is normal behaviour so I'm still stuck with the original problem as to why the redirect occurs.

**CLARIFICATION**

-- I enter `http://portalt` in the browser and land on `http://portalt/company/intranet/en/Pages/Portal.aspx` (correct behaviour)

-- I click on a link 'Favourites' and land back on `http://portalt/company/intranet/en/Pages/Portal.aspx` (`http://portalt/company/intranet/en/Pages/Favourites.aspx` is expected)

The correct behaviour occurs in browser on the server.

In IIS, the host bindings contain just http, *:80

Alternate access mapping: (internal)`http://portalt`; (Zone)Default; (public)`http://portalt`

**FURTHER UPDATE**

I was surprised to see that (so far) only my IE and Firefox that have the problem. Chrome works fine. In Firebug I see that the requested page returns 302 and then the main page gets reloaded. In Chrome the requested page returns 200 and continues to load. Strange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a shot in the dark here but you say that on the server its fine but on your pc its not, also have you check to see if its only your pc behaving like that and have you looked at the htaccess and hosts file to see if there is any rules?

**EDIT**

Now we know its only your pc, try using another browser to see if its local to that browser your using. If it is than reinstall that browser or update.

**EDIT 2**

next stage is to see if its you user account, can you try on your pc that is having the issue but this time with a different login credentials? if it works then its related to that account if it doesnt than its 100% related to the browsers but im going with the browsers as it works in chrome!

try this also please to rule out ie setting being changed, this will reset all the setting this will solve any loopbacks that might be set on ie

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Reset-Internet-Explorer-settings

Comment: +1 it is just my pc! I really hadn't expected that and have no idea why this is happening. There is nothing in hosts and I cannot find any htaccess files on the server.

Comment: yes, tried IE and FF which both have this behaviour. Chrome works as expected. All work when I access the (almost) identical production server, portalp

Comment: also, IE and FF both work for a colleague. I gave him the same rights as me and still works.

Comment: Please refrain from discussion style comments on this Q/A forum. If you want to discuss details about the Q use the chat. Also the above is not an answer.

Comment: can you please explain how the above is not an answer? if you can explain to me how its not i will add it as an edit to my answer and delete the comments

Comment: the bounty is due and your **answer** helped me get on the right track. The problem is not yet finally solved as I have had to do other work over the past few days. I will mark this as the correct answer and my thanks to the others who also helped! When I get this issue sorted I'll post an update.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a problem with the alternate mappgins.

Go to the central admin -> manage web applications -> config alternate mappings and see what is defined for your web application.

It must be something that the IIS also acepts for that site, so looking in IIS might also be helpful.

One question: are you typing portalt:80 on the browser or is it just the in the log?

Comment: I'm just entering http://portalt in the browser

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely check IIS for hostheaders, clear all hostheaders from IIS that is SharePoint related. SharePoint should be handling any normal hostheader requests through "Alternate Access Mappings"(AAM)

You can get to AAM by:

1. Navigate to your Central Administration of the SharePoint web
   front-end.
2. Go to your System Settings on the left panel
3. Click "Configure alternate access mappings"
4. Click "Alternate Access Mapping Collection drop-down" to change to your web application
5. Make sure that the default URL is correct (without port 80, as port 80 can be left off the URL because it is implied when using http)
   and nothing is being redirected to and from it in IIS.

If you have a DNS entry, you may enter it here under Edit Public URLs and define the zone you want the URL in.

Comment: Thanks! I've added a checked these settings and they seem to be ok. See 'Clarification' in my post

Comment: I would try creating a new site collection and see if redirection happens there as well. Do you have any custom masterpages?

Comment: Yes, there is a custom page. However, the problem seems to be on my pc - see Further Update

Answer (score 1):

Please verify if the following settings are not enabled/configured in [IIS](http://www.iis.net/):

- [HTTP Redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732969%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- [URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

*These settings allows to to perform URL manipulation tasks*

[image]

### HTTP Redirection

[image]

### URL Rewrite module

See picture below as en example  of IIS Rewrite with configured
Rules.

[image]

Comment: Http redirect is not configured. Cannot find Url Rewrite (IIS 6.1)

Answer (score 1):

Here's [a link to a blog post by Alex Zubair](http://blog.techgalaxy.net/archives/445) that lists common AAM problems (it's a bit oldish, but seems to be relevant). Pay attention to the following paragraph:

> You are redirected to `http://computer_name` when browsing to your
>   site. If Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 receives a request from an
>   unrecognized URL (or a URL that has not been configured for alternate
>   access mappings), and you have installed the Infrastructure Update for
>   Windows SharePoint Services 3.0, Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 tries
>   to determine the correct Web application and then responds to the
>   request by using the same base URL in the links on the page that it
>   returns.

Answer (score -2):

Can you check if this behaviour is just on your pc or its happening on a different machine too apart from that if I was you I would perform following tests if its happening on different machines,

- While opening website check Network tab to see how redirect is happening, You can also look at Http gets and see if you can find any clue. At same time check if some thing appears in ULS logs as in case if someone deployed anything while you was on holidays, it might help to look at old logs in event receiver as well, 302 is used for temporary redirects btw.

[image: Chrome Developer tools Network tab]

- Use [Http Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083667/sharepoint-2007-warmup-script-alternative-to-http-request) using C# to check what response you are getting for web pages and check properties just like we do in warm up scripts.

Comment: please dont reiterate what i have already posted and please read other answers and op problem before you address the matter! as iv already asked him your origional question there wasnt any need for you to reiterate what i have already said, also reading through other answers youll see that he hasnt got any errors on server what led me to ask the question weather it was local to only his pc ;) ! thanks